# request is null when posting to app deployed on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to POST to the server I've deployed on heroku but the "request" variable on my server seems to be null since i tried using request.get_json() resulting in a crash.

I've tried to test the server locally by using pytest to test the servers functionallity and when doing it, it works perfectly. No errors or warnings. It only happens when it's deployed to heroku. My test payload I'm trying to post to the server is '{"firstname": "pelle", "lastname": "Johansson", "phonenumber": 0323256327, "email": "test@gmail.com", "password": "abbe123"}'

Server code for handling the post request (server.py)

```
@app.route('/user', methods=["POST"])
def new_user():
    # Checking if request is available
    try:
        in_data = request.get_json()
    except:
        return jsonify({'msg': 'Could not get a request'}), 422

    # Checking the parameters so they contain the right data
    try:
        in_data = request.get_json()
        foo = in_data['firstname']
        foo = in_data['lastname']
        foo = in_data['phonenumber']
        foo = in_data['email']
        foo = in_data['password']
    except:
        return jsonify({'msg': 'One or more fields are missing values'}), 422
```

The main function also on the same file as above (server.py)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug=True
    port1 = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507))
    app.run(port=port1)
```

What I'm trying to get is a 200 code return with a json attached to it. The problem is that the request variable is empty when the server is deployed on heroku and i try to POST to it.